# natural structure morphism from Proj $S$ to Spec $A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a finitely generated graded $A$ algebra, where $A$ is a commutative ring with unity. The exercise says to describe a natural structure morphism from Proj $S$ to Spec $A$. 
I would appreciate some assistance! Thanks!

Comment: I could answer, but I would like to ask you this : what does mean being a finitely generated graded $A$-algebra ? I mean, you could for sure translate this into the existence of some surjective graded morphism $A[T_0,\ldots,T_n]\to S$, isn't it ? Then, knowing the definition of $\textrm{Proj}(S)$, couldn't you come up with a morphism $\textrm{Proj}(S)\to \textrm{Spec}(A)$ ? How would you, to an homogenous prime ideal of $S$ not containing the *irrelevant* ideal, associate a prime ideal of $A$, knowing that $S$ is a quotient of an homogeneous polynomial ring over $A$ ?...

Comment: To define a morphism from $X:=Proj S$ to $Spec A,$ it is enough to define a ring homomorphism from $A$ to $\Gamma (X, \mathcal O_X)$ (R.Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Ch. II, Ex. 2.4). Now define $\phi: A \to \Gamma (X, \mathcal O_X)$ by $\phi (a)(\mathfrak p) = \frac{a}{1} \in S_{(\mathfrak p)},$ the homogeneous localization of $S$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak p.$ Then $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism and consequesntly we have a morphism $f: X \to Spec A.$

Comment: @Krish There's an explicit formula.

Comment: @Krish Could you possibly explain a little more on how $\phi$ is defined? I am little bit confused on how it is defined...

Comment: @user10000100_u or could you possibly tell me what the explicit formula is?

Comment: Here is a link: http://therisingsea.org/notes/TheProjConstruction.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is an $A$-algebra, then there is a canonical morphism Spec $B \to$ Spec $A$.

Now if $S$ is a graded $A$-algebra, then Proj $S$ is a union of various Spec $B$'s, as $B$ ranges over certain $A$-algebras, constructed from localizations of $S$.
Each Spec $B$ has its canonical morphism to Spec $A$, and these are compatible on overlaps, defining the required morphism Proj $S \to$ Spec $A$.

Comment: What is the ring morphism from $A$ to $B$ that corresponds to the morphism Spec $B$ to Spec $A$?

Comment: Also, could you possibly explain me why the maps are compatible on the overlaps? Thanks!